# Can MongoDB be packaged in an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, electron

Can I package MongoDB in an Electron app so I don't need to install it on a client's machine?  I'm developing an app on OSX and it will probably be used on Windows.  Do I need to separately install Mongo on the clients?

Comment: You'd probably need to require the client to have MongoDB installed. What is your use case? In most cases I would say MongoDB for desktop application storage to be overkill

Comment: @kontrollanten  I just need a lightweight nosql db to store files and do basic crud operations.  There won't be that much data stored, but the files could be fairly large (up to 20mb or so pdfs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. I have used this method in the past.  It brings in mongod.exe and launches it.

Take a look here to see how it is done.

https://github.com/nosqlclient/nosqlclient-electron/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 7):

The simple and obvious answer is: No. MongoDB is AFAIK not *embeddable*, at least not in any sense of the word *straightforward*.

But the *real* question is, what problem do you want to solve?
Perhaps is [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) the database, you want to ship with your app.

Comment: I just want to find a nosql db that will let me store files and read/write data that can be bunled with Electron.  I can't have the user install the db separately

Comment: Why use a DB to store files instead the obvious solution `filesystem`?

Comment: You're right, I don't actually need to store the files with the DB.  I'm migrating this from a Firebase app to a solution that will need to work completely offline, hopefully with as little change as possible to the structure of the code.  Is PouchDB embeddable?

Comment: It is in as far "embeddable", as it is a "client side" DB which is in the context of "Electon" _embedded_.

Comment: @DavidJ. Forgive my French, but using a database to locally store files is utter nonsense. It adds a layer of complexity (and wastes resources!), let alone the fact that FireBase is hardly comparable with MongoDB or PouchDB. So you would have to basically refactor the CRUD anyway. So you can refactor it to use a filesystem. Portable, simple, resource friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use [indexeddb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) which is a JavaScript-based object-oriented database.

Comment: what are the practical limitations on the size of the stores in Indexeddb?

Comment: @Vass browser storage limitations and eviction criteria is outlined in this post https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria but as mentioned in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128994/8398300 you can calculate the quota size and prevent eviction of your data.

Comment: would you say that at the extended size, that the DB is as fast and efficient as mysql for instance?

Comment: I would say the database (with or without extended size) could never as efficient as a standalone database instance. Remember indexeddb is running atop the browser and is a much watered down version of a NoSQL database.