# Embed/package mongodb with electron builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

is there a way to ember Embed/package mongodb installer with electron builder.

I have tried npm/github repos, and find none.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can MongoDB be packaged in an Electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926506/can-mongodb-be-packaged-in-an-electron-app)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bundle MongoDB with Electron.

Quoting from this site: https://www.techiediaries.com/electron-data-persistence/

> **Pros and Cons of Using MongoDB**
>
> For the pros of using MongoDB with Electron apps:
>
> - Available for all Electron suppored platforms such as Windows, Linux
>     and MAC. So it doesn't limit the cross platform feature of Electron.
> - Can be installed and integrated easily with Electron.
>
> There are also some cons:
>
> - Can't be bundled with Electron so the end users need to install it
>     separately from your application.
> - Overkill for small apps.

There are some other persistent databases you can package with Electron, such as NeDB, that you might consider trying.